# Convert postgres RealDictRow into custom Json format with Key and Values in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm querying postgres using the psycopg2 package in python. I'm getting the query results back in RealDictRow object since I'm using the RealDictCursor factory. Here is what the data looks like;

```
[RealDictRow([('customer_id', 'a1'), ('firstname', 'bob'), ('lastname', 'smith'), ('email', 'foo@example.com'), ('account_created', datetime.date(2019, 10, 24))]), RealDictRow([('customer_id', 'a2'), ('firstname', 'gavin'), ('lastname', 'mayhew'), ('email', 'foo2@example.com'), ('account_created', datetime.date(2020, 1, 2))])]
```

I need to convert this into the following json format;

```
[
    {
        "keys":{
                "customer_id": "a1"
                },
        "values":{
                "firstname": "bob",
                "lastname": "smith",
                "email": "foo@example.com",
                "account_created": "2019-10-24"
                }
    },
    {
        "keys":{
                "customer_id": "a2"
                },
        "values":{
                "firstname": "gavin",
                "lastname": "mayhew",
                "email": "foo2@example.com",
                "account_created": "2020-1-2"
                }
    }
]
```

I've tired using the json package like below;

```
import json

def datetime_handler(x):
        if isinstance(x, datetime.date):
                return "{}-{}-{}".format(x.year, x.month, x.day)
        raise TypeError("Unknown Type")

json_data = json.dumps(cursor.fetchall(), default=datetime_handler)
```

However this just gives me the json sting `[{"customer_id": "a2" ... }]`

How would i go about formatting it in the way I need ?

Any advise is appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What I have done to get a json-like object while keeping it in Python is:

```py
cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
query = "SELECT * FROM table"

cursor.execute(query)
data = cursor.fetchall()

data = [dict(row) for row in data]
```

This doesn't solve the problem of getting datetime objects to be JSON Serializable however.

Depending on your use case and the need to return a JSON (not just access a `dict`) you will want to either review the `simplejson` library or write your own JSON Serialization Class or method (as you've done in your question).

You may also want to consider adding the `datetime.datetime` instance to your method.

Answer (score -1):

Turn fetch response to str with `json.dumps()` and after return to JSON using `json.loads()`

Example:

```
def get_names():
        operator.execute("SELECT * FROM items")
        response = json.dumps(operator.fetchall())
        newRes = json.loads(response)
        print(response)
        print(newRes)
        return newRes
```

Look the log:

```
//String Type:
[{"id": 1, "name": "Teste1"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Teste2"}, {"id": 10, "name": "Teste3"}, {"id": 11, "name": "Teste4"}]
//JSON Type
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Teste1'}, {'id': 12, 'name': 'Teste2'}, {'id': 10, 'name': 'Teste3'}, {'id': 11, 'name': 'Teste4'}]
```

In this case, my table has `id` and `name` columns.